# Rest Controller: uploading file using HttpServletRequest through Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I wonder if it is possible to show the input file to select in my Swagger UI when exposing the API.
I confirm that it is working perfectly when defining the endpoint as following:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> upload(@RequestPart MultipartFile file)
```

There is no doubt to show the file chooser when using `MultipartFile`.

[image: file chooser]

And as I would like to upload big files, I have to use `HttpServletRequest` instead in order to upload the file as a stream. The endpoint will be then like:

```
public @ResponseBody Response<String> upload(HttpServletRequest request) {
            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
            // Parse the request
            FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    FileItemStream item = iter.next();
                    String name = item.getFieldName();
                    InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                            String filename = item.getName();
                            // Process the input stream
                            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                            IOUtils.copy(stream, out);
                            stream.close();
                            out.close();
                    }
            }
            return new Response<String>(true, "Success", "");
}
```

The endpoint is working well using a curl command. But unfortunately when using the Swagger UI, I am not able to show the file chooser. 
Does anyone faced the same case or knows if Swagger supports this feature?